# Evolutionary Algorithm doesn't seem to get any progress

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I'm trying to evolutionize values in order to tune them but I feel my code isn't  good enough. My biggest problem is that the values are ranged from -.5 to .5 which makes it really hard to follow what came from which parent. (BTW What I'm evolutionizing is weights in neural network)

```
def mutate_array(self, inher1, inher2):

    shape = inher1.shape
    random_values = 2 * np.random.rand(*shape) - 1
    mutatings = np.random.rand(*shape) < self.entropy
    one_chance = (np.random.rand(*shape) <= 0.5)
    new_values = np.array(inher2)
    new_values[one_chance] = np.array(inher1[one_chance])
    new_values[mutatings] += random_values[mutatings]
    return new_values
```

Where inher1 and inher2 are 2 arrays from the parents, and self.entropy is a varialbe changing(also evolutionarily) between 0.05 - 0.2

What I get when I try this is a complete failure.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking. What exactly is the problem? What is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior? "complete failure" isn't really helpful.